# How to positioning an image between two div

Tags: html, css, position

i have to positioning an image between the bottom of two div, one inside another like:

[image: example]

The code for this example is:

```
<div style="background:blue;width:500px;height:150px;overflow:hidden;">
   <div style="background:red;width:500px;height:100px;margin-top:20px;">
    //DOES IMAGE GOES HERE?
   </div>   
</div>
```

I know that with position absolute i could positioning the image there.. but i don't like that kind of positioning.. is there another way? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full css sample

```css
.blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  /* half of image height */
  right: 10px;
  /* right space */
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
  <div class="red">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Hey now used to this

```
.parent{
background:blue;
  width:500px;
  height:150px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.child{
background:red;
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
  margin-top:20px;
  position:relative;
}
.child img{
position:absolute;
  bottom:-25px;
  right:6%;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```css
.parent{
background:blue;
  width:500px;
  height:150px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.child{
background:red;
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
  margin-top:20px;
  position:relative;
}
.child img{
position:absolute;
  bottom:-25px;
  right:6%;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/250x100/">
   </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: it works good!!! i edited bottom to 0px so it is centered between the two div.. but.. (i'm on 13inch screen size) if i see on a bigger screen? is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div style="background:blue;width:500px;height:150px;overflow:hidden;">
   <div style="background:red;width:500px;height:100px;margin-top:20px; 
               padding-left: 250px ; padding-top: 50px">
    //IMAGE GOES HERE.
   </div>   
</div>
```

padding would help to leave space.

Comment: i have other element in inner div

Comment: if you have other elements in inner div then please share the structure of mark-up , so we can find out the appropriate tag within which img tag can be placed.

Answer (score 0):

The best is:

**HTML**

```
<div style="background:blue;width:500px;height:150px;overflow:hidden;">
   <div style="background:red;width:500px;height:100px;margin-top:20px;position:relative;">
    <img src="" style="position:absolute;bottom:-10px;" />
   </div>   
</div>
```

I have add absolute positioning.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mgNCf/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
<div style="background:blue;width:500px;height:150px;overflow:hidden;">
   <div style="background:red;width:500px;height:100px;margin-top:20px;">
   </div>   
   <img src="imageNemaHere" width="134" height="28" style="float:right; margin:-10px 10px 0 0" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `position:relative`

```
<div style="background:blue;width:500px;height:150px;overflow:hidden;">
   <div style="background:red;width:500px;height:100px;margin-top:20px;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x40" style="position:relative;left:400px;top:80px">
   </div>   
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ABEne/